# Undefined property in a .getValues ()

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's the code I try to run :

```
function Validation () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetPlanif = ss.getSheetByName('Planification');
  var sheetTdB = ss.getSheetByName('TdB');
  var sheetLiv = ss.getSheetByName('Livraisons');
  var planifIndex = sheetPlanif.getLastRow();                                               

  var columnIndex = sheetLiv.getLastColumn();

  for (var j=2; j<=rowIndex; j++) {
    var codeD = sheetLiv.getRange(j,1).getValue();
      if (codeD == "") {
        sheetLiv.deleteRow(j);
      };
  };

  var day1length = sheetPlanif.getRange(3,1,planifIndex,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(day1length[0][0]);
  for (var k=0; k<=planifIndex; k++) {
    if (day1length[k][0] != "") {
      var rowIndex = sheetLiv.getLastRow();
      sheetPlanif.getRange(k+3,1,1,6).copyValuesToRange(sheetLiv, 1, 6, rowIndex, rowIndex);
    };
  };
  sheetPlanif.clear().hideSheet();
  sheetLiv.getRange(2,1,rowIndex-1,22).sort(3);
}
```

When I do so, I keep having the same error : "Impossible to run read property "0" from undefined" because of the day1length[k][0]. However, when I print any of the day1length values I get a proper a value.

Do you know why I can't run the loop? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop, is looping the number of iterations of the length of rows:

```
var planifIndex = sheetPlanif.getLastRow();
for (var k=0; k<=planifIndex; k++) {
```

Change this line:

```
for (var k=0; k<=planifIndex; k++) {
```

To:

```
for (var k=0; k<=day1length.length; k++) {
```

Imagine if you have 10 rows in your spreadsheet, `planifIndex` would be 10.  So, your `for` loop will loop 10 times (`k` starts at zero and goes to 9).

But the number of of rows of data that you are getting is only 7:

```
var day1length = sheetPlanif.getRange(3,1,planifIndex,1).getValues();
```

It starts at row 3, and goes to 10 - length of 7.  So, when your `for` loop gets to count 8, there's no data left, you'll get an error.

Comment: Hi Sandy, thx for your detailled explanations. However I keep having the same error even after applying the modification. I ll investigate.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the debugging tools, one of the best things you can do is read the troubleshooting documentation.  [Link to Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)  If you can show the new code and know what line is giving the error, that will help.